# Jquery show div witth the same class as clicked link

Tags: jquery, show

I have several divs, all of which are displa:none; by default. Each has the same class as the link to close them. My code gets the class of the clicked link correctly, but I can't figure out how to target the div with the elementClass variable.

```
$("a").click(function(){

    var elementClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("div.elementClass").show();
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concantenate the variable

```
$("a").click(function(){

    var elementClass = $(this).attr("class");
    $("div." + elementClass).show();
    return false;

});
```

and note that `attr("class")` returns all the classes of the element, so if the element has more than one class, they all have to match etc.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`elementClass` is a variable so you should treat it like one. What you are looking for in your call is a div whose class is called elementClass and you don't want that.

You need to change it to the following:

```
$("div."+elementClass).show();
```

Comment: Obviously I know it's a variable. I just didn't know how to get it to act like one.